# How to use GTK/GNOME notifications services in Java?

Tags: java, gtk, notification

I've started learning Java and to have some project to actually put knowledge to the practice, I decided to make a custom notifications service. I know that Java is not the best option, but that's what I decided, it's just for me.

So my question is: what APIs do I need to use to create it? I guess it's GTK...

And one more: can you give any tutorial about actually programming that kind of notifications?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer (TL;DR):**
Use [Java-Gnome bindings](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/), it is a native library that enables Java applications to use GTK and GNOME APIs/Services.

**Long Answer:**
Java official slogan is "write once, run anywhere", where it states that Java programs can be run on various platforms (processors) and operating systems. To do that, the Java programming language provides a generic platform and operating system (a virtual machine) for 
application development (API), instead of native (operating system) one.

Thus, to use a specific operating system API, one must do native calls. By doing that, Java cannot guarantee that your code is portable anymore. 
[Java-Gnome](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/) is a native library that exposes GTK and GNOME APIs to Java applications.

**See an example in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030004/java-program-using-gnome-java-will-not-compile**

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I got one more question, stupid newbie question... Where is located the library, if I installed it using apt?

Comment: The library jar is located in:  `/usr/share/java/gtk.jar`, and the native library is located in: `/usr/lib/jni/libgtkjni-4.1.2.so`.


You will need to add the native library to your environmnet, you can do that by adding `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni/` to the java command line.